# How to make a displaybox application that prompts user for length and width and then displays a box of asterisks

Tags: java, methods, parameters

I want to make a box of asterisks that utilizes the user's length and width, using methods, parameters and loops (no arrays if possible since I haven't learned it yet.) What I have so far just displays one line of the asterisks, I have no idea what to do past this point. Please help!

```
    public static void drawBar(int length, String mark) {

    for (int i = 1; i < length; i++) {
        System.out.print(mark);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a height: ");
    int length1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a width: ");
    int length2 = input.nextInt();

    for (int j = 1; j < length1; j ++) {
        drawBar(j, "*");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: You need a second loop to manage the height, which wraps around the loop which writes the row

Comment: @madprogrammer he already has two loops that wrap each other.  the code is just structured a bit weird. @Zaki: your length variable is not scoped correctly. youre passing `j` to drawBar instead of length2. I think it will run correctly if you fix that. You could also put the for loop from drawBar directly into your first method. This will make  your code easier to read and understand the control flow

Comment: @MadProgrammer I'm fairly knew to Java so could you show me how I would set a second loop to manage the height.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Should I use a while statement instead of a for statement.

Comment: nevermind I got it

Comment: thank you guys for the answers

Comment: @MenzoWijmenga That's true, but where does `length2` come into play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UIException {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a height: ");
    int height = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter a width: ");
    int width = input.nextInt();

    String mark = "*";

    for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {//Number of lines it will repeat the process
        System.out.println(new String(new char[width]).replace("\0", mark));// "\0" is nul character that will be replace the N number of times needed to fill the width.
    }
}
```

You should also begin the for loop with 0, in must of the programming languages you always start counting in zero